# How to send messages to telegram using Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I have a python script in which logs messages to the console. But I also want those messages to be sent to the telegram using my bot.

Any hint and suggestion will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

I haven't tried anything yet, just got thought if that possible or not and if it is then how?

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). First you need to do research. StackOverflow is not a place for others to "write your code" - you should try things first, and once you have an error, search for it here. If you don't find a solution, then it's okay to ask a new question.

Comment: Its very generic ask. You have to add some code here for us to help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Make A Telegram Bot Using BotFather for Telegram
   Search for BotFather in your Telegram client by opening it. A pre-installed Telegram bot that assists users in making original Telegram bots
   To create a new bot, enter /newbot.
   Name and username your bot.
   Copy the token for your new Telegram bot.
   Please take note that anyone who obtains your token has complete control over your Telegram bot, so avoid uploading it online.
2. Obtaining a chat ID
   To send Telegram messages using Python, we require the conversation ID that each chat in Telegram holds.

Send a message to your Telegram bot (any random message)
Use this Python program to locate your chat ID.

```py
import requests
TOKEN = "YOUR TELEGRAM BOT TOKEN"
url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/getUpdates"
print(requests.get(url).json())
```

The `getUpdates` function, which is invoked by this script, sort of checks for new messages. Our chat ID can be located in the JSON that was returned (the one in red)

Please take note that your results can be empty if you don't message your Telegram bot.
Copy the chat ID and paste it in the following step.

3. Python-based Telegram message delivery
   The following Python script requires you to enter 1) your Telegram bot token and 2) your chat ID from the previous two steps. (Be sure to include modify your message.)

```py
import requests
TOKEN = "YOUR TELEGRAM BOT TOKEN"
chat_id = "YOUR CHAT ID"
message = "hello from your telegram bot"
url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text={message}"
print(requests.get(url).json()) # this sends the message
```

Run the Python script and check your Telegram!